# Transpose of two lists with different length

Tags: list-manipulation

I solve the equation of form $f(x,y,z)=0$ numerically for a given list `{x,y}` and put roots `z0` into array. For several values $x$ & $y$ there is more then one root of equation.

Then I would like to organize the nested list with structure `{ {x,y}, z }` where `z` can be a list. For instance,

```
   {   {x1,y1},{{z1,z2,z3}}  }
```

There is no problem to do it,

```
Transpose[{xyarray,zroots}]
```

gives me desirable result. But then I stuck with several problems:

1. How can I obtain the list of roots with structure

   ```
   {   {{x1,y1},z1}, {{x1,y1},z2}, {{x1,y1},z3}, ...}
   ```

   I can do it with many manipulations with Transpose but I believe that there is more simple way
2. Suppose that I have not only list of roots but list of pairs `{z1, g[z1]}` where $g$ is simple and known function. I compute list `g[zarray]`
   and then organize list of pairs. Finally, I work with list with structure

   `{  {{x1,y1},{   {z1,g[z1]}}, {z2,g[z2}},  {z3,g[z3]}   },...  }`

In this list I would like to do several things. First, extract all the elements with $g(z_i)<0$. I understand how to do this with `Cases`, no problem. Then, I would like to obtain list with structure

```
{   {{x1,y1},{z1,g[z1]}},   {{x1,y1},{z2,g[z2]}, ...}
```

**Therefore, finally** I look for the following manipulation with lists:

```
{ {{x,y},list} }----->{  {{x,y},list[[1]]}, {{x,y},list[[2]]},... }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two alternatives that seem to produce the format you want:

```
original = {{{1, 2}, {z1, z2, z3}}, {{5, 5}, {z7, z8, z9}}};
Flatten[Distribute[{{#1}, #2}, List] & @@@ original, 1]
Flatten[Outer[List, {#1}, #2, 1] & @@@ original, 2]

(* Out:
{
 {{1, 2}, z1}, {{1, 2}, z2}, {{1, 2}, z3}, 
 {{5, 5}, z7}, {{5, 5}, z8}, {{5, 5}, z9}
} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: This does indeed work with the pairs that @ArtemAlexandrov explicitly indicates they want to modify. I think it might be helpful if you clarify this point, you can use the `lister` I defined in my answer if you’d like. Good show!

Answer (score 3):

```
list1 = {{{1, 2}, {z1, z2, z3}}, {{5, 5}, {z7, z8, z9}}};

list2 = MapAt[{#, g @ #} &, list1, {All, 2, All}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {{z1, g[z1]}, {z2, g[z2]}, {z3, g[z3]}}},
>  {{5, 5}, {{z7, g[z7]}, {z8, g[z8]}, {z9, g[z9]}}}}
> ```

A few additional methods:

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3]
f1 = Join @@ (Tuples[{{#}, #2}] & @@@ #) &;
f2 = Join @@ Map[Thread[#, List, {2}] &]@# &;
f3 = Join @@ (Transpose[{ConstantArray[#, Length@#2], #2}] & @@@ #) &;

f1 @ list1
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, z1}, {{1, 2}, z2}, {{1, 2}, z3}, 
>  {{5, 5}, z7}, {{5, 5},  z8}, {{5, 5}, z9}}
> ```

```
f1 @list2
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {z1, g[z1]}}, {{1, 2}, {z2, g[z2]}}, {{1, 2}, {z3, g[z3]}},
> {{5, 5}, {z7, g[z7]}}, {{5, 5}, {z8, g[z8]}}, {{5, 5}, {z9, g[z9]}}}
> ```

```
f1 @ # == f2 @ # == f3 @ # & @ list1
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

```
f1 @ # == f2 @ # == f3 @ # & @ list2
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Say you’ve got you list as such:

```
list=Array[{#1,#2}&,{1,10}][[1]]

(* {{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{1,6},{1,7},{1,8},{1,9},{1,10}} *)
```

Then you can do like so

```
{{x,y},list[[#]]}&/@Range@Length@list

(* {{{x,y},{1,1}},{{x,y},{1,2}},{{x,y},{1,3}},{{x,y},{1,4}},{{x,y},{1,5}},{{x,y},{1,6}},{{x,y},{1,7}},{{x,y},{1,8}},{{x,y},{1,9}},{{x,y},{1,10}}} *)
```

This is my go to for a lot of things I do. It can likely be done in a better way but hey! It works.

If you want to do the equivalent process on a set of these, you can do the following:

```
Cases[{a__List,b__List}:>({a,b[[#]]}&/@Range@Length@b)][original]//Flatten[#,1]&
```

Using `original` as defined by MarcoB, it produces the same output they show.

This same syntax can turn this

```
lister={{{x1,y1},{{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{1,6},{1,7},{1,8},{1,9},{1,10}}},{{x2,y2},{{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{1,6},{1,7},{1,8},{1,9},{1,10}}}};
```

Into this

```
Cases[{a__List,b__List}:>({a,b[[#]]}&/@Range@Length@b)][lister]//Flatten[#,1]&

{{{x1,y1},{1,1}},{{x1,y1},{1,2}},{{x1,y1},{1,3}},{{x1,y1},{1,4}},{{x1,y1},{1,5}},{{x1,y1},{1,6}},{{x1,y1},{1,7}},{{x1,y1},{1,8}},{{x1,y1},{1,9}},{{x1,y1},{1,10}},{{x2,y2},{1,1}},{{x2,y2},{1,2}},{{x2,y2},{1,3}},{{x2,y2},{1,4}},{{x2,y2},{1,5}},{{x2,y2},{1,6}},{{x2,y2},{1,7}},{{x2,y2},{1,8}},{{x2,y2},{1,9}},{{x2,y2},{1,10}}}
```

Comment: Is this the format requested though? I understood them to start out with e.g. `{ {{1, 1}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{5, 5}, {7, 8, 9}} }` and wanting `{ {{1, 1}, 1}, {{1, 1}, 2}, {{1, 1}, 3}, {{5, 5}, 7}, {{5, 5}, 8}, {{5, 5}, 9}, etc etc }`

Comment: Unfortunately, it do not seem what I need and @MarcoB is right

Comment: @MarcoB that makes sense. I was only going off of the last point/request that ArtemAlexandrov stressed. I’ll come back to this a bit later & submit something regardless.

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov I am confused then what your ultimate end goal is. I show how to do essentially what you have iterated at the end of your question as what you want to happen. This is why I show it with a list of pairs as you indicate. It would be helpful to clarify this point. Please help me to understand what it is you want to achieve.

Comment: @CATrevillian I try to clarify as I can. The answer by MarcoB is exactly what I look for

Comment: Does it work with the pairs you explicitly indicate you want it to work with?